# Is is possible to add 4 handlers to a jquery slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a slider to show opening hours and pause time.
I need 4 handlers but I only have 2 handlers.
My code now allows to only select the opening hours.
I also need to select pause time inside the opening hours.
How do I add 2 handlers for showing the pause time inside the opening times?
I already have this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slider").each(function() {
        // $this is a reference to .slider in current iteration of each
        $this = $(this);
        // find any .slider-range element WITHIN scope of $this
        $(".slider-range", $this).slider({
            range: true,
        min: 0,
    max: 1440,
    step: 15,
    values: [420, 1020],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
               var hours1 = Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 60);
        var minutes1 = ui.values[0] - (hours1 * 60);

        if (hours1.length == 1) hours1 = '0' + hours1;
        if (minutes1.length == 1) minutes1 = '0' + minutes1;
        if (minutes1 == 0) minutes1 = '00';
        if (hours1 > 9) {
            if (hours1 == 12) {
                hours1 = hours1;
                minutes1 = minutes1;
            } else {
                hours1 = hours1;
                minutes1 = minutes1;
            }
        } else {
            hours1 = "0"+hours1;
            minutes1 = minutes1;
        }
        if (hours1 == 0) {
            hours1 = 0+"0";
            minutes1 = minutes1;
        }
        var hours2 = Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 60);
        var minutes2 = ui.values[1] - (hours2 * 60);

        if (hours2.length == 1) hours2 = '0' + hours2;
        if (minutes2.length == 1) minutes2 = '0' + minutes2;
        if (minutes2 == 0) minutes2 = '00';
        if (hours2 > 9) {
            if (hours2 == 12) {
                hours2 = hours2;
                minutes2 = minutes2;
            } else if (hours2 == 24) {
                hours2 = '00';
                minutes2 = "00";
            } else {
                hours2 = hours2;
                minutes2 = minutes2;
            }
        } else {
            hours2 = "0"+hours2;
            minutes2 = minutes2;
        }
               $(this).parent().find(".amount").html( hours1 + ':' + minutes1 + ' - ' + hours2 + ':' + minutes2);
            }
        });
        
   
     });
});
```

```css
 #time-range p {
    font-family:"Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#333;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal {
    height: 14px;
    background: #D7D7D7;
    border: 1px solid #BABABA;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF, 0 1px 0 #CFCFCF inset;
    clear: both;
    margin: 8px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -ms-border-radius: 6px;
    -o-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.ui-slider {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
max-width: 400px;
}
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range {
    top: -1px;
    height: 100%;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-range {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 14px;
    font-size: .7em;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #5BA8E1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #AAD6F6 inset;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: #81B8F3;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgi…pZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZ3JhZCkiIC8+PC9zdmc+IA==');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #A0D4F5), color-stop(100%, #81B8F3));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A0D4F5, #81B8F3);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #A0D4F5, #81B8F3);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #A0D4F5, #81B8F3);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #A0D4F5, #81B8F3);
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #F9FBFA;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgi…pZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZ3JhZCkiIC8+PC9zdmc+IA==');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #C7CED6), color-stop(100%, #F9FBFA));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C7CED6, #F9FBFA);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C7CED6, #F9FBFA);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #C7CED6, #F9FBFA);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #C7CED6, #F9FBFA);
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0 -1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 0 1px 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0 -1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 0 1px 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0 -1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset, 0 1px 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) inset;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .3s;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow .3s;
    -o-transition: box-shadow .3s;
    transition: box-shadow .3s;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: -3px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: default;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -4px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4px;
    background: #30A2D2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 1px rgba(22, 73, 163, 0.7) inset, 0 1px 0 0 #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 1px rgba(22, 73, 163, 0.7) inset, 0 1px 0 0 white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 1px rgba(22, 73, 163, 0.7) inset, 0 1px 0 0 #FFF;
}

.ui-slider a:focus {
    outline:none;
}
.slider-range {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#time-range {
  width: 100%;
max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
            
            <div style="width: 70px; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">Monday</div>
           <span class="amount"  > 08:00 - 17:00</span>
      <div class="slider-range"></div> 
            
 </div><br/>
```

Is it possible at all?
It should look like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKHQ9.png)

Has anyone a idea on how to do this?

Comment: looking on google I found an example similar to what you want to do, I hope you can help

 https://jsfiddle.net/5vhyyp37/3/

Comment: Thanks ill check